# turning the black to alpha in texture node

Tags: materials, transparency

How to turn the textures ( for example musgraves ), black color area to alpha color channel .
I have tryed to findt a manual that would solve the problem , but have only findt
how to make an alpha channel come out of a picture not from a texture node.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the only thing you can do in a shader is to use the texture as input to the alpha input of a shader node that supports alpha input, like the principled shader node.  Here's an example of a red ball behind a brick wall:

[image: red ball behind brick wall with transparent 'mortar']

Here's the simple shader for this.  Note that I inverted the color of the brick mask before feeding to the alpha input of the principled shader.  Otherwise, the mortar would have been black and the bricks transparent:

[image: shader that produces the effect]

Note that if you are going to render this with EEVEE you need to go to the material settings and change the Blend Mode to Alpha Blend:

[image: enable alpha blend for transparency effect]